# How to download data from azure-storage using get_blob_to_stream

Tags: django, python-3.x, azure, azure-storage

I have some files in my azure-storage account. i need to download them using get_blob_to_stream.it is returning azure.storage.blob.models.Blob object. so i couldn't download it by using below code.

```
def download(request):
    file_name=request.POST['tmtype']
    fp = open(file_name, 'wb')
    generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(container_name)
    for blob in generator:
        print(blob.name)
        if blob.name==file_name:             
            blob=block_blob_service.get_blob_to_stream(container_name, blob.name, fp,max_connections= 2)    
        response = HttpResponse(blob, content_type="image/png")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename="+file_name
        return response
```

Comment: Are you trying to just download the blobs, or specifically as a stream to be processed further ? Or are you trying to download it locally to your computer ?
get_blob_to_stream: Downloads a blob to a stream, with automatic chunking and progress notifications. Returns an instance of Blob with properties and metadata.

Comment: @AdamSmith-MSFT i am trying to download the file to the local system

Comment: was the provided answer helpful?

Comment: Was the answer provided in the post helpful for you? if so please mark it as an answer to help the community that could be asking a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use the **get_blob_to_path** property, below is an example in python:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

bb = BlockBlobService(account_name='', account_key='')
container_name = ""
blob_name_to_download = "test.txt"
file_path ="/home/Adam/Downloaded_test.txt"

bb.get_blob_to_path(container_name, blob_name_to_download, file_path, open_mode='wb', snapshot=None, start_range=None, end_range=None, validate_content=False, progress_callback=None, max_connections=2, lease_id=None, if_modified_since=None, if_unmodified_since=None, if_match=None, if_none_match=None, timeout=None)
```

This example with download a blob file named: "test.txt", in a container, to File_path"/home/Adam/Downloaded_test.txt" , you can also keep the same name if you'd like to as well. You can find more samples including this one in https://github.com/adamsmith0016/Azure-storage

Comment: How would I use `get_blob_to_stream` in an Azure Function with BlobTrigger? Or is `func.InputStream` the equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use get_blob_to_stream. You can download with below code:

```
with io.open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
    blob = block_blob_service.get_blob_to_stream(
           container_name=container_name,
           blob_name=blob_name, stream=file, 
           max_connections=2)
```

Just note that the file content will be streamed to the file rather than the returned blob object. The blob.content should be None. That is by design. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/issues/538.